# $parse fails on date expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a component that somewhere inside that component it has a code like this:

```
var getAttribute = $parse(attrs[key]);
```

when `$parse` service is passed a string like this`2017-03-06 14:40:19` it fails and produce the following error:

`Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '14' is an unexpected token at column 12 of the expression [2017-03-06 14:40:19] starting at [14:40:19].`

can anyone tell me what is wrong with this whole thing?

Comment: `[2017-03-06 14:40:19]` doesn't look like a string to me. Can you make sure?

Comment: it is actually a date object, you can check exact code here :https://github.com/AminRahimi/angular-bootstrap-persian-datepicker/blob/master/persian-datepicker-tpls.js#L583

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$parse is a service which accept only string as arguments. So processing date object is not possible through $parse service. so first apply your date object to $filter. Then the result will be a string type. Which can be accessible through $parse service.

```
var collectionDate = '2002-04-26T09:00:00'; 
collectionDate = $filter('date')(collectionDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy'); //string format
collectionDate = $parse(collectionDate);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I still have problem with your solution, I use it like `minDate: $filter('date')(new Date())` and it gives me the error `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '6' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression [Mar 6, 2017] starting at [6, 2017].`, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I could have know the scenario that you are looking for?

Comment: if you take a look at here: https://github.com/AminRahimi/angular-bootstrap-persian-datepicker/blob/master/persian-datepicker-tpls.js#L583, I am passing some options to a directive and that directive internally use `$parse` service for those options which in this case are date objects and that causes error.